# C++: Compile such that I no longer need to link sub objects

Tags: c++, compilation, g++

For instance, suppose I have a cpp, `fileB.cpp` which depends on `fileA.cpp`,

```
g++ -o fileA.o -c fileA.cpp
g++ -o fileB.o -c fileB.cpp fileA.o
```

Now, later, I want to compile `fileC.cpp`, which depends on `fileB.cpp`.  However, I don't want to have to have all of the sub objects used to create `fileB.o`.

When I compile with

```
g++ -o fileC.exe fileC.cpp fileB.o
```

I fail, but when I compile with:

```
g++ -o fileC.exe fileC.cpp fileB.o fileA.o
```

...I succeed.

---

There must be a way to "seal off" the compiled `fileB.o` object so that I no longer need to keep track of `fileA.o`...???

Comment: It looks like you are looking for a static library which is essentially just a pack of obj files.

Comment: That's what makefiles and other build systems are for.

Comment: A single object file is create from a single [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (basically one source file and all its included header files). You need to link with all object files. Using a build system like `make` or similar will help you handle all of that.

Comment: Have you tried `g++ -c -combine fileA.cpp fileB.cpp -o fileAB.o` ?

Comment: @super I think this is what I am looking for. Thanks man.